# Arcanist Error parsing field "Subscribers"

Tags: arcanist

when apply `arc diff`, it report error `Error parsing field "Subscribers"`, but `"Subscribers"` is not a required fields, so i think it should not report error.

when i put the valid infomation for `"Subscribers"`, it alse report the same error, Does anyone know how I should handle this?

error is:

```
Launching editor "vim"...
Provide the details for a new revision, then save and exit.
Commit message has errors:

      - Error parsing field "Reviewers": The objects you have listed include
      objects which do not exist (korov).
      - Error parsing field "Subscribers": The objects you have listed
      include objects which do not exist (#, Tip:, You, can, mark, a,
      reviewer, as, blocking, by, adding, an, exclamation, ("!"), after,
      their, name.).
      - Invalid or missing field "Reviewers": You must provide a Reviewers.

You must resolve these errors to continue.

    Do you want to edit the message? [Y/n] n

Usage Exception: Message has unresolved errors. A copy was saved to commit message.
```

message is:

```
update

Summary:update

TaskID:
None

Reviewers:
korov

Subscribers:

# Tip: You can mark a reviewer as blocking by adding an exclamation mark ("!")
# after their name.

# NEW DIFFERENTIAL REVISION
# Describe the changes in this new revision.
#
# Included commits in branch dev:
#
#         5585b7eed1fc update
#
# arc could not identify any existing revision in your working copy.
# If you intended to update an existing revision, use:
#
#   $ arc diff --update <revision>
#
# NOTE: commit 5585b7eed1fc could not be completely parsed:
#   - Error parsing field "Subscribers": The objects you have listed include objects which do not exist (#, Tip:, You, can, mark, a, reviewer, as, blocking, by, adding, an, exclamation, ("!"), after, their, name.).
```